# Problems with jquery calls in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Let me tell you that I am a beginner of Ajax and Jquery along with asp.net, 
I have a aspx page with backend coding in c#. 
I ahve a single update panel which contains a asp:table an in turn, one column contains a form with two fields and a button to add a department of the organisation, and the other column of a table contains a gridview to list all the departments of the organisation.

My problem: whenever i submit a form in the update panel,

### some times it shows a message in the left column as "Department has been added successfully", and sometimes gridview will be updated, and sometimes none of the above two changes(even though the department has been added in database), and sometimes neither the changes are made, nor the department is added in the database.

After working on the same, came to know that, the second time submission of form is doing nothing. first time everything is working perfectly, but when am submitting the second department, $.POST() is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make it work without an update panel. Make it work without ajax (step through the code), then add the .net ajax components afterwards. If you're a beginner, it helps to break the problem apart, start small and add fancy features once the core functionality is working.